# Positioning div in aside

Tags: html, css, position

I'm currently developing.

**My problem is** :
I have an aside with 2 div in it, in these 2 div there's a list.

When div are block they're positioning automatically on top of the aside.
When I want them to be inline-block (which one take 50% width of the page), if one list is longer than the other, the smallest div is automatically positioning at the bottom of the aside.

Is there an easy and clean way to position them both at the top of the aside ?

I'm pretty sure the solution is right in front of my eyes and I've already did it but maybe you can tell me better solution.

For example

```css
.aside1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.aside1>div {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: normal;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.aside2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.aside2>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: normal;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>example 1</h2>

<aside class="aside1">
  <div class="div1">
      <ul>
        <li>Num 1</li>
        <li>Num 2</li>
        <li>Num 3</li>
      </ul>
  </div><div class="div2">
      <ul>
        <li>Num 1</li>
        <li>Num 2</li>
        <li>Num 3</li>
        <li>Num 4</li>
        <li>Num 5</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</aside>

<h2>example 2</h2>

<aside class="aside2">
  <div class="div1">
    <ul>
        <li>This div</li>
        <li>is at</li>
        <li>the bottom</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
      <ul>
        <li>This div</li>
        <li>is positioning</li>
        <li>normally</li>
        <li>at the</li>
        <li>top</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Thank you !

Comment: Apply a `min-width` of `50%` to the nested `div` elements, this should allow that width to expand should any list item exceed the minimum width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `.aside2>div`

Answer (score 0):

A good idea could be to use CSS **flexbox**:

```
.aside2{
    display:flex;
    align-items: top;
    [The rest of your rules]
}
```

More about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

See the working snippet below:

```css
.aside1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.aside1>div {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: normal;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.aside2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
}

.aside2>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: normal;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>example 1</h2>

<aside class="aside1">
  <div class="div1">
      <ul>
        <li>Num 1</li>
        <li>Num 2</li>
        <li>Num 3</li>
      </ul>
  </div><div class="div2">
      <ul>
        <li>Num 1</li>
        <li>Num 2</li>
        <li>Num 3</li>
        <li>Num 4</li>
        <li>Num 5</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</aside>

<h2>example 2</h2>

<aside class="aside2">
  <div class="div1">
    <ul>
        <li>This div</li>
        <li>is at</li>
        <li>the bottom</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
      <ul>
        <li>This div</li>
        <li>is positioning</li>
        <li>normally</li>
        <li>at the</li>
        <li>top</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it's work

```
.aside1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.aside1>div {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: normal;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.aside2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.aside2>div {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: normal;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
}
```